# Escaping PHP in functions printing HTML pages

Tags: php, html

Currently can't figure out how to properly escape a php function in my printing functions that output my HTML pages.

For example, I have a page called removeClient, where I want to remove a client according to it's ID. A drop down box should supply the user with the current client ID's available and they should have the ability to click on one.

I have a main page where functions get called according to the view supplied by the URL.

Now, I want the page to print the drop down menu with the IDs supplied by a Postgres Database, then some forms to fill in the new user data.

Function that gets called is as following;

```
    function removeClient() {

    include 'dbconnect.php';

    if ((isset($_POST['add']))) {

        if (isset($_POST['ID']) && (isset($_POST['FirstName'])) && (isset($_POST['LastName'])) && (isset($_POST['IP'])) && (isset($_POST['Status']))) {
            $clientid = $_POST['ID'];
            $FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
            $LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
            $ip = $_POST['IP'];
            $status = $_POST['Status'];

            $result = pg_query($dbconnection, "somequery");

            if (@pg_affected_rows($result) === 1) {

                echo "<p> Client removed!</p>";
            } else {

                echo "<p> Something went horribly wrong. Contact a system adminstrator </p>";
            }
        }
    }


    echo

    "<form name=\"addClient\" method=\"post\" action=\"?view=addClient\"/><br/>" .
    "<select name=\"clientID\" id=\"clientID\">         " .
    "<td>ID</td> <tr><input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"32\" name=\"ID\" /></tr><br/>" .
    "<td>First Name</td> <tr><input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"32\" name=\"FirstName\" /></tr><br/>" .
    "<td>Last Name</td> <tr><input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"32\" name=\"LastName\" /></tr><br/>" .
    "<td>IP Addr.</td> <tr><input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"32\" name=\"IP\" /></tr><br/>" .
    "<td>Status</td> <tr><input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"32\" name=\"Status\" /></tr><br/>" .
    "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"add\" value=\"Send\" /></form><br/>";
}
```

Now, what I want to do is to change the line 
     "         " .

to a line where Postgres loads her database values in through PHP.

For the PHP part, I got this;

```
    <option>Select userID</option>
<?php
$db = pg_connect("connection details") or   die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
$sql = pg_query("SELECT title FROM books WHERE ownedby='$user_id'";
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($row['title']).'"></option>';}
pg_close($db);
?>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="userid" id="userid" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($user_id); ?>">
```

Now, I'm not sure how to implement this in echo calls printing HTML pages. I've tried to do a lot of escaping but it is not helping yet. How can I efficiently add this piece of code to my form structure, echo'd in php?

Comment: You habe no "option label" set for all of your options. The label for the option comes between `<option>` and `</option>` and the `value` attribute defines which value gets submitted if you choose the specific option label.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo <<<_HTML
```

`<html code>`
`_HTML;`

using this way to write html code in echo or print.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the param `ENT_QUOTES` is missing in htmlspecialchars ?

```
htmlspecialchars($row['title'], ENT_QUOTES)
```

Also, check the `htmlspecialchars` (and / or `htmlentities`) documentation to see the others params (the 3rd is about charset )

**EDIT:** I m not sure the `<option value="something"></option>` can display the value, so maybe you should also try this:

```
echo '<option>'.htmlspecialchars($row['title'], ENT_QUOTES).'</option>';}
```

Answer (score 0):

As TiMESPLiNTER pointed out - you need to change this:

```
echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($row['title']).'"></option>';}
```

to

```
echo '<option>'.htmlspecialchars($row['title']).'</option>';}
```